# sympy eliminate or chancel unwanted results

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to solve the **cosine formula** using sympy. (A is angle and a, b, c is sides)

```
sol = solve(a**2-b**2-c**2+2*b*c*cos(pi/180*A), [A, a, b, c])
print(sol)
```

And I end up getting results like this:

```
[(90.0000000000000, 5.00000000000000, 4.00000000000000, 3.00000000000000), (270.000000000000, 5.00000000000000, 4.00000000000000, 3.00000000000000)]
```

But it's impossible for a triangle to have a 270º interior angle.

I tried to do `A, B, C <= 180` and `solve(a**2-b**2-c**2+2*b*c*cos(pi/180*A), [A<=180, a, b, c])`.I also try to use `exclude=[A<=180]` in the `solve()`, but it don't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand what's happening:

```
from sympy import *
a, b, c, A = symbols("a, b, c, A")
eq = a**2-b**2-c**2+2*b*c*cos(pi/180*A)
```

`eq` is a trigonometric equation involving the cosine function, which is periodic with a period of `2*pi`. Suppose you want to solve `cos(x) = y` where `y` is contained in `(-1, 1]`: you will get two solutions! For example, suppose you want to solve `cos(x) = 0.5`: one solution is `x=60deg` and the other is `x=300deg`.

Now let's focus on your equation. You have one equation with 4 symbols. Let's assume that `a,b,c` are known quantities and asks Sympy to solve for `A` (the unknown, which I assume it is the angle in degrees).

We can filter out the solutions in two approaches.

#### First approach

Substitute the known values `a, b, c` into `eq` and then solve for `A` with a specified constraint:

```
# substitution dictionary
d = {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
# solve the equation asking to find the solution for which A <= 180
sol = solve([eq.subs(d), A <= 180], A)
print(sol)
# out: (-oo < A) & (A <= 180) & (Eq(A, 60) | Eq(A, 300))
```

Here, SymPy produced a boolean solution (meaning it is a combination of one or more solutions with the `And` and `Or` objects). Let's try to simplify it a bit:

```
sol2 = sol.as_set()
print(sol2)
# out: {60}
```

Now we can extract it with:

```
A_num = list(sol2)[0]
print(A_num)
# 60
```

#### Second approach

Obtain a fully symbolic solution, then substitute the known values and filter out according to your rules:

```
sol = solve(eq, A)
for i, s in enumerate(sol):
    print("sol", i+1, ":", s)
# output:
# sol 1 : 180*(-acos((-a**2 + b**2 + c**2)/(2*b*c)) + 2*pi)/pi
# sol 2 : 180*acos((-a**2 + b**2 + c**2)/(2*b*c))/pi

# substitution dictionary
d = {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
sol = [s.subs(d) for s in sol]
# apply custom filter:
sol = [s for s in sol if s <= 180]
sol = sol[0]
print(sol)
# out: 60
```